# Exponent operator does not work when no space added? Whats wrong with my grammar

Tags: parsing, ebnf, cocor

I am trying to write an expression evaluator in which I am trying to add underscore _ as a reserve word which would denote a certain constant value.

Here is my grammar, it successfully parses `5 ^ _` but it fails to parse `_^ 5` (without space). It only acts up that way for ^ operator.

```
COMPILER Formula
CHARACTERS
    digit = '0'..'9'.
    letter = 'A'..'z'.
TOKENS
    number = digit {digit}.
    identifier = letter {letter|digit}.
    self = '_'.
IGNORE '\r' + '\n'

PRODUCTIONS
    Formula = Term{ ( '+' | '-')    Term}.                                              

    Term = Factor {( '*' | "/" |'%' | '^'   ) Factor}.

    Factor = number | Self.

    Self = self.
END Formula.
```

What am I missing? I am using Coco/R compiler generator.

Comment: Other than a missing period after the `Formula` production, which I assume is a typo here on SO, I don't see any obvious issues. What's the error you get with the `_ *  5` input?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Posted an update

Comment: Does it work if you take out the `letter` and `identifier` definitions (that are currently unreferenced)? - I think your `letter` definition might be causing problems as it includes characters between 'Z' (upper case) and 'a' (lower case).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes it works. Please post your answer, I will accept it. I will edit my question to highlight the real issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current definition of the token `letter` causes this issue because the range `A`..`z` includes the `_` character and `^` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the Formula and Term rules like this:

```
Formula = Formula ( '+' | '-') Term  | Term                                             

Term = Term ( '*' | "/" |'%' | '^'   ) Factor | Factor
```

e.g. https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Marpa-R2/pod/Marpa_R2.pod#Synopsis

Comment: Coco/r can't handle left recursion.